# Storing an Event Timeline in Redis

Tags: node.js, data-structures, redis, sortedset

I'd like to store a list of events in a timeline in Redis. I'm thinking of a sorted set with seconds since 1970 as the score, allowing quick lookup and range searches.

The problem is I want each of these events to represent an object, with a couple of keys (about 3 maybe), so I'd store a sorted set of IDs - the application would then lookup the hash based on the ID.

So the conversation would go something like this:

```
> ZRANGEBYSCORE events start end 
1) "16"
2) "17"
> HGETALL events:16
1) "key1"
2) "val1"
...
> HGETALL events:17
...
```

Is there a better way to organise or do things that would avoid the application making a separate call for each result. Could everything be done on the redis-server side to avoid this overhead? Is it even a big problem?

PS. I'm using the node client, but my question applies to other languages too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious solution is to work by value instead of working by reference. So your zset could store serialized objects instead of storing the references on these objects. With node, JSON is easy to use.

Now, if you need to keep the current structure (because for instance some of your objects are shared by various zsets), then you need to think in term of rountrips rather than commands. What is expensive in Redis is the roundtrip, not really the execution of the O(1) command itself.

HGETALL does not support variadic parameters (i.e. you can only retrieve one hash object). But Redis is quite good at processing pipelined commands, and this is especially easy to do from the node_redis driver due to the asynchronous nature of node. So in your example, you just need 2 roundtrips: the first one to perform the ZRANGEBYSCORE, and a second one to perform all the HGETALL commands (i.e. do not wait the result of the first HGETALL command before issuing the second one). It will be quite efficient.

With the current Redis version (2.4), there is no way to eliminate the second roundtrip.

Comment: We use this exact approach for something similar.  Also the Redis scripting branch should let you do this in a single trip

Comment: Would there not be drawbacks to storing all this info in one field? Like storing a csv in a rdbms field? Is that just the trade-off for speed?

Comment: There is no real drawback when the objects are small. There is a drawback when the objects are bigger, and you want to support partial update, or when you want to share the objects from various containers. Regarding your remark about csv, all database systems have to serialize the rows (mysql, postgreSQL, Oracle, etc ...). Most of them support variable-length data (with separators, or size prefixes). The format they use is binary, optimized, but in term of complexity, the cost of serialization is not that different from the one you could have with a simple csv row.

Comment: @DidierSpezia Sounds like a good solution for me then. The drawback I was talking about with the CSV column is not based on performance, but ideal practice. Storing multiple values (delimited by eg. a comma) in one field of a table is not considered best practice in terms of normalisation (performance aside). In terms of Redis, storing these serialised objects like this might stop me from searching the set based on any of the objects' properties, though I'm not yet sure if this will be something I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could stringify the object and store it as a stringwith `JSON.stringify()` and then retrieve it with `JSON.parse()`